# How to change css style of input element of V-Calendar package?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I need advice. I use [V-Calendar](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar) package where I want to customize style of `input` element. I use such code but this method yielded no results.

```
<template>
    <v-date-picker
        class='date-picker'
        mode='range'
        v-model='range'
        :show-day-popover=false
        is-double-paned
        show-caps>
    </v-date-picker>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .date-picker input{
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        color: #495057 !important;
        background-color: #fff !important;
        background-clip: padding-box !important;
        border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
        transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out !important;
        padding: .25rem .5rem !important;
        font-size: .875rem !important;
        line-height: 1.5 !important;
        border-radius: .2rem !important;
    }
</style>
```

The second question is how to remove this pointer:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `scoped` for css, I suggest you using deep selector

```
.date-picker /deep/ input {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    color: #495057 !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    background-clip: padding-box !important;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out !important;
    padding: .25rem .5rem !important;
    font-size: .875rem !important;
    line-height: 1.5 !important;
    border-radius: .2rem !important;
}
```

[Deep selector reference](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

Comment: Thank you! What can you advice about my second question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your second question. Could you explain more detail?

Comment: I want to remove arrow (`^`) . In the post you can notice little picture at the bottom.

Comment: Well, finally I found solution for my second question: `.popover-content:after{content: none !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tweak with the `.direction-*` classes, especially the borders. Checking the hover event you can see that it inserts an element with a class `.direction-*` -- `*` meaning: top, left, right and so on. [Here's](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/blob/e53eeb3b62b18098bfbeaa9de0877acd8f75f583/src/components/Popover.vue) the link from the source, look how it add some pixels depending where the `popover` is located.

At first, try some `!important` rules until you find the correct fix. Also you can recompile the file to suit your needs. Don't forget the `borders` from the `.popover-*` classes, also located at the link.

It looks like the event add the code inline, so it might be a problem.